# Selective request-throttling using akka-http stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, backpressure

[image]

I got one API which calls two another Downstream APIs. One downstream api (`https://test/foo`) is really important and it is very fast. Another slow downstream api (`https://test/bar`) has its limitation, the throughput of it only can handle 50 requests per sec.

I would like to make sure the downstream api `https://test/foo` has more priority than `https://test/bar`. For example, if the API thread pool is 75, I only allow 50 parallel incoming connection to go through `https://test/bar`. Rest of the connections should be used for `https://test/bar`. It would make `https://test/bar` never fails.

I guess I should apply throttle or maybe buffer with OverflowStrategy.dropNew for `https://test/bar`.

Here is the code snippet.

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("api")
implicit val flowMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val httpService = Http()

val serverSource: Source[Http.IncomingConnection, Future[Http.ServerBinding]] =
  httpService.bind(interface = "0.0.0.0", 3000)

val binding: Future[Http.ServerBinding] =
  serverSource
    .to(Sink.foreach { connection =>
      connection.handleWith(
        Flow[HttpRequest]
          .map {
            case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/priority-1"), _, _, _) =>
              HttpResponse(entity = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://test/foo").mkString)
            case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/priority-2"), _, _, _) =>
              HttpResponse(entity = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://test/bar").mkString)
          }
      )
    }).run()
```

**Question 1**: where should I put `throttle(50, 1 seconds, 5000, ThrottleMode.Shaping)` to conform to only `https://test/bar` threshold.

**Question 2:** do I need to apply *buffer* and *OverflowStrategy.dropNew* if I want to prioritise `https://test/foo` requests. In another words, all unnecessary connections for `https://test/bar` should be removed.

**Question 3:** Is there a better way to implement this requirement. I am using `connection.handleWith[Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse]]` in Sink and I am not sure this is right place.

If there are some **code snippet** provided, that would be much appreciated and super awesome :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the routing DSL instead? https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/overview.html

Comment: Given that, you should never use blocking IO inside akka-http routes - so consider either wrapping these IO operations in `Future`s (and give them separate execution contexts to facilitate priorities) or using an async HTTP client (akka http has a client, for example)

Comment: Yep I can use request => future[response] rather than Flow[request, response]. That is actually what I did before. However, if I am using future, I guess it is not totally related to the way handling selective route throttling. :)

Comment: You need a throttling directive, that based on some configuration (e.g. specific request path) and number of req/s would either pass the request further or respond with something like 408. You can check: https://github.com/adhoclabs/akka-http-contrib for inspiration.